csrf token missmatch laravel
Used Laravel 8
======= Google translate
When users sign up, I provide a website screen where they can select various account types.
When the user selects a type, the mobile phone authentication process begins.
The process proceeds as a pop-up opens.
Once identity verification is complete, the pop-up window closes and moves to the membership registration page.
The FORM is submitted and the method moves on to POST.
Setting the method of the certForm tag to POST was used to prevent users from entering the URL and going to the membership registration page without authenticating themselves.
My current problem is that identity verification is completed normally, the pop-up window is closed, the certForm tag is submitted, and the page is moved.
And I get a csrf token missmatch error.
What's the problem?
Here's my code.
    public function verify(Request $request) {
        $identityVerification = new IdentityVerification();
        $iv = $identityVerification->verify($request->post());
        
        if($iv["Resultcd"] == "0000") {
            echo "<script>window.opener.document.getElementById('cert').value = 'ok';</script>";
            echo "<script>alert('DONE.');</script>";
            echo "<script>window.opener.document.certForm.submit();</script>";
            echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('FAILED');</script>";
            echo "<script>location.href = '/login';</script>";
        }
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.register-type');
    }

<div>
    <?php

    $Siteurl       = "Crack.com";
    ... some Code
    ?>

    <div>
        <main style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.5rem;">start</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; gap: 1rem; text-align: center; margin-top: 2rem;">
                <div>
                    <div style="row-gap: 3rem; height: 100%; padding: 1rem; border: 1px solid rgb(110 174 211); border-radius: 1rem; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                        <a href="javascript:verifyNumber('/register-school');">
                            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; padding: 1rem; background-color: rgb(110 174 211);">
                                <span>
                                    This Button
                                </span>
                                <img src="/assets/img/tap.png" width="40">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style="row-gap: 3rem; height: 100%; padding: 1rem; border: 1px solid rgb(235 185 185); border-radius: 1rem; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
                        <a href="javascript:verifyNumber('/register-company');">
                            <div onclick="" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; padding: 1rem; background-color: rgb(235 185 185);">
                                    This Button 222
                                </span>
                                <img src="/assets/img/tap.png" width="40">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>

    ... some Code
    <form name="payForm" accept-charset='euc-kr' method="GET">
        @csrf
        ... some Code
        <input type="hidden" name="Siteurl" id="Siteurl" value="{{$Siteurl ?? ''}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="route" id="route" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
    
    <form method="post" name="certForm">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="cert" id="cert" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>

    <script>
        function verifyNumber(route) {
            document.certForm.action = route;
            PAYMENT(document.payForm);
        }
    </script>
</div>


An identity verification function has been added to each membership registration page.


window open A window opens, and after identity verification is completed, the window closes and a page expiration notification appears after a while.


I tried changing the method of certForm, but
The logic of requiring identity verification was not followed.

I tried changing the callback URL after authentication expired, but the symptom was the same.

I looked up when the csrf token expires and is renewed, but I did not understand.



I think that when you send some new output to the browser (echo "<script>) the @csfr token set in the page is no more valid. Since you're using Livewire, use this system to handle things

@TUPKAP Thanks reply
you mean browser csrf token doesn't work cuz I used script tag in server response ?
sorry guy. I dont understand word that you wrote "use this system to handle things"  how to ???
I tryed it but, i can't
I tried connect livewire public variable and view input and remove a "echo sciprt" tags in server outputs and

When you send any output to the browser, you are sending a new page, even if you don't see the results. So the @csfr token has changed. The technique you use to send commands in javascript to the browser is very dated and questionable, it is preferable to use AJAX calls instead. Since you are using Livewire you should use it to let it do the bulk of the work. Try searching for "livewire modal" and you'll find some examples.
